# Decompose in simple elements

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$F(x)= \frac{(x^2+2x+5)}{(x^2-3x+2)}$$
$$F(x)= \frac{(x^2+2x+5)}{(x-2)(x-1)}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^{2}+2x+5}{\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)}=\frac{x^{2}-3x+2+5x+3}{\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)}=1+\frac{5x+3}{\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)}$$

Assume $\frac{5x+3}{\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)}$ is in the form:

$$\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x-1}$$
Then $$x\left(A+B\right)-\left(A+2B\right)=5x+3$$

So $-\left(A+2B\right)=3$ and $A+B=5$

Solving for $x$ gives:
$A=13$ and $B=-8$

Answer (score 0):

This is known as "partial fraction decomposition".  The first step is to make sure the numerator is a lower degree than the denominator.  That is not the case here.  Therefore, to begin, you need to do polynomial long division.  After that division, the numerator will be in the form where the numerator is a lower degree than the denominator.

Then, you have already factored the denominator, so you assume that you can decompose the result into the form:

$$\frac{A}{x - 2} + \frac{B}{x - 1}.$$

Then you cross-multiply these to get:

$$\frac{Ax - A + Bx - 2B}{(x - 2)(x - 1)}$$

Then you set that equal to the numerator, and can solve for $A$ and $B$.